# Why is the ring of matrices of order $n$ is an algebra - Gantmacher?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Please, I'm reading "The Theory of Matrices" by Gantmacher. The author says in section 3, p. 17: "Since in this ring the operation of multiplication by a number of $F$ is defined, and since there exists a basis of $n^2$ linearly independent matrices in terms of which all matrices of order $n$ can be expressed linearly, the ring of matrices of order $n$ is an algebra."  I don't understand the second clause.

Also there is a related footnote that says that an arbitrary matrix $A = [a_{ik}]_1^n$ with elements in $F$, can be represented in the form $A = \sum_{i,k=1}^n ([a_{ik}][E_{ik}])$ where $E$ is the matrix of order $n$ in which there is a $1$ at the intersection of the $i$-th row and the $k$-th column and all the other elements are zero. Nor do I understand the relation between this footnote and the fact that the ring of matrices is an algebra.

My understanding is that an algebra is a vector space equipped with the binary operation of multiplication. And the ring of matrices is an associative algebra since we can multiply matrices with the associative properties. But how can I interpret the above text in light of my understanding.

May someone explain with examples (I'm still beginner in abstract algebra)?
Sorry for the bad math text, I had to write it from my phone.

Comment: The book is pre-1950, right? The notion of an algebra wasn't set in stone back then. For some, it would have meant a vector space with a basis and an explicit multiplication table.

Comment: @darij Yes, it is pre-1950. Please, what do you mean by an explicit multiplication table?

Comment: I mean that the multiplication, instead of being defined as a bilinear map, is understood to be the table of all products of two basis vectors (or "structure coefficients", i.e., the coordinates of such products written with respect to the basis).